# Windows 10 unexpectedly restarting

Tags: windows, windows-10, java, jdk

I encountered a very strange problem after installing Java JDK 8. Whenever I create a new Java project in Eclipse Luna, my computer unexpectedly restarts without any warning or anything else.

I'm pretty sure the culprit is JDK 8 because I uninstalled it and ran a game to check if it's not graphics card issue or anything.

After reinstalling the JDK, the same problem occurs again.

I seriously need help on this as I want to create a college assignment.

I'm currently running a 64-bit system. 
The JDK I installed was also 64-bit. 
I also installed JDK 32-bit, but encountered same problem. 
Same thing happens with JDK 7.

Any suggestions will appreciated.

Here's the screenshot of whoCrashed:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you have the same problems with jdk 7?

Comment: I'll give it a try and report back

Comment: Same thing happens with Jdk7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took my PC to a shop and they told me that having multiple JREs in Windows 10 sometimes corrupts the graphics driver.

So I unstalled JDK and JRE 6 which is I don't know when I installed which conflicts with JRE 8 somehow.

Then I downloaded a graphics driver and performed a **clean install** and the problem was gone.

Comment: ?!?! that makes absolutely no sense... Glad (and amazed) that they knew about it

Comment: It may be an issue in the graphics driver, in theory even without the JVM java shouldn't lock up the whole machine if it crashes

Comment: Even I am confused and thought thay what jvm has to do with graphics driver but it may be a issue with windows 10 itself however I am not sure

Answer (score 1):

If you get a BSOD or there's a crash dump, you can use http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed

Comment: I have tried whoCrashed and posting the screenshot

Comment: Go to the dump files tab and find your latest crash dump file on disk